# How to react with skin tones in slack API

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm trying to add a reaction with a set skin tone.

The example emoji is :princess::skin-tone-5:

so far I've tried,

- `princess` followed by `skin-tone-5` (which reacts with princess and a skin colored square)
- `princess:skin-tone-5:` (does not work)
- `princess` (normal princess emoji)

Here is the code:

```
react_to_message("princess", channel, timestamp)

def react_to_message(emoji, channel, timestamp):
    slack_client.api_call("reactions.add", name=emoji, channel=channel, timestamp=timestamp)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question was asked and answered on the Slack API twitter account: https://twitter.com/slackapi/statuses/728725775361388547

So in your case you would use `princess::skin-tone-5`.